# Material which absorbs water on carpet and hardwood floor?

Tags: water, hardwood-floor, carpet

As the title says, I am looking for material or ways to suck water quickly from hardwood floor or carpet.

Comment: How much, how often, under what conditions, and why doesn't a wet/dry shop vacuum meet your needs?

Comment: We are potty training our 2 yr old and she makes a mess from time to time.

Comment: That's a somewhat different question, since you want to wash the surface, not just mop it. Dealing with cats, I find sponges/mops/paper towels followed by an enzyme-based odor-killing floor cleaner is quite adequate.

Comment: 2YOs don't produce all that much liquid at a time; how about paper towels?

Comment: @DanielGriscom We have to use atleast 4 paper towels and paper towels are expensive(atleast I feel) so looking for easy and cheap options if there are any. May be my question is not that clear. Sorry for that.

Comment: Keep a set of rags/towels for the purpose, laundered for reuse?

Comment: @keshlam, rag/towel doesn't seem to absorb water as efficiently as paper towels. I am not trying to make it difficult but looking for some powder or something to throw on the damp/wet carpet so that it dries quickly.

Comment: Disposable diapers, or the absorbant polymer they contain? The latter can be ordered in bulk, but you may need to go to a company that deals specifically with workplace safety and order it as HazMat spill cleanup material. Locally, look for the powder used to quick-solidify excess paint. But  grabbing a diaper you already have on hand, and cutting it open if you just want the absorbant, may be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2):

A wet (typically "wet/dry") vacuum - most commonly the most affordable form is a shop vacuum. You can use it like a "carpet cleaner" (which is a more expensive form) by spraying a cleaning solution and then sucking that up with the vacuum. Most are quite loud.

[image: A wet/dry shop vacuum]

*Image is an example of the type, not an endorsement of a particular brand or supplier.*